# ColdFusion cfdocument CSS counter-increment counter

Tags: css, coldfusion, cfdocument

The HTML/CSS below works in recent browsers, but not in CF9's cfdocument.  Anyone with ideas?

**WHAT DO I KNOW?**
Yes! I am aware that CF's cfdocument supports a limited set of CSS properties.
The CF documentation says counter-reset, counter-increment and counter are supported.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**
GROCERIES:
  1) Apples
  2) Bananas
  3) Cantelopes

**EXAMPLE CODE**

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" pagetype="letter" 
    margintop="0.5" marginbottom="0.5" 
    marginleft="0.5" marginright="0.5">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        li { list-style-type: none; }
        ol { counter-reset: ordered; 
          padding-left: 0.5em; 
          border: solid 1px #F00; 
        }
        li:before { counter-increment: ordered; 
          content: counter(ordered) ") "; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <strong>GROCERIES:</strong><br>
    <ol>
      <li>Apples</li>
      <li>Bananas</li>
      <li>Cantelopes</li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
</cfdocument>
```

Comment: +1 for reading the supported properties list :)

Comment: Reference: cfdocument's supported CSS properties [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c21.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think it may help to specify the list-style-type, this below should get you closer.  It has has decimal points after the numbers:

GROCERIES:

1. ) Apples
2. ) Bananas
3. ) Cantelopes

---

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" pagetype="letter" 
    margintop="0.5" marginbottom="0.5" 
    marginleft="0.5" marginright="0.5">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        ol {list-style-type: none;}
        li:before {content: counter(section, decimal) ") ";}
        li { counter-increment: section;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <strong>GROCERIES:</strong><br>
    <ol>
        <li>Apples</li>
        <li>Bananas</li>
        <li>Cantelopes</li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
</cfdocument>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I've played around with your example.  I didn't realize my CSS wasn't correct.  It seems like the li:before works in cfdocument as expected.  It's the counter that is not showing up. Arggg!

Comment: FWIW, I get the same results as Tim. Did you use the exact code above? What version of CF are you running?

Comment: Here's what I meant about the counter not showing up.  If you replaced the line: content: counter(ordered) ") "; with the following: content: "X" counter(ordered) ") "; you will see what I mean.  BTW: I was running CF9 and received the same results as Tim.